# How do I retrieve the ranking of a user from a materialized view?

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views

I am using Cassandra for storing contest data.

Currently I have a contest table like this (table contest_score):

[image]

And I created a materialized views for ranking users in a contest (table contest_ranking):

[image]

For get top 10 users of a contest I can simple query select top 10 from contest_ranking;

But how can I get ranking of specific user. For example: user_id = 4 will have rank 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principal philosophy of data modelling in Cassandra is that you need to design a CQL table for each application query. It is a one-to-one mapping between app queries and CQL tables.

Since you have a completely different application query, you need to create a separate table for it. Here's an example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE rank_by_userid (
    user_id int,
    rank int,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)
```

You can then get the rank of a user with this query:

```
SELECT rank FROM rank_by_userid WHERE user_id = ?
```

You have to manually create and maintain this new table because you won't be able to populate it with materialized views. Cheers!

Comment: Assume the new table named user_ranking. How to maintain the user_ranking table ? I think I will create a job run every 5 minutes, it will read data from contest_score table and update the user_ranking. It mean I may have to accept the incorrect ranking during the maintain process.

Comment: It is a typical use case for Spark to maintain the ranking table. Cheers!